# (node:14264) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ISSUER] DeprecationWarning: Module.issuer: Use new ModuleGraph API

Tags: webpack, node-modules, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to build the project using "npm run build:dev" but keep getting this following error regarding webpack.

> webpack --config src/build/webpack.config.js  --mode=development                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    (node:14264) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_ISSUER] DeprecationWarning: Module.issuer: Use new ModuleGraph API                                                                (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)                                                                                         (node:14264) [DEP_WEBPACK_TEMPLATE_PATH_PLUGIN_REPLACE_PATH_VARIABLES_HASH] DeprecationWarning: [hash] is now [fullhash] (also consider using [chunkhash] or [contenthash], see documentation for details)                                                                                                                            assets by status 51.5 KiB [cached] 5 assets                                                                                                                        assets by status 2.96 MiB [emitted]                                                                                                                                  assets by status 2.13 MiB [big]                                                                                                                                      asset common.3ab7d3de4d278107a7ff.js 965 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [big] (name: common) (id hint: vendors) 1 related asset                                         asset vendor.bundle-f7b30ab365ebd10b7aa4.js 708 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [big] (name: vendor) (id hint: vendor) 1 related asset                                   asset feature-maps-components.d7eab29db58187c695c9.js 511 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [big] (name: feature-maps-components) 1 related asset                        + 10 assets                                                                                                                                                      Entrypoint app [big] 898 KiB (1.37 MiB) = vendor.bundle-f7b30ab365ebd10b7aa4.js 708 KiB app.bundle-f7b30ab365ebd10b7aa4.js 189 KiB 2 auxiliary assets              orphan modules 14.3 KiB [orphan] 23 modules                                                                                                                        runtime modules 8.86 KiB 12 modules                                                                                                                                modules by path ../ 1.31 MiB 469 modules                                                                                                                           modules by path ./ 1010 KiB                                                                                                                                          modules by path ./Components/Feature/ 846 KiB 239 modules                                                                                                          modules by path ./core/ 84.9 KiB 48 modules                                                                                                                        modules by path ./Components/Global/ 23.9 KiB 27 modules                                                                                                           modules by path ./PushNotifications/js/ 19.5 KiB 9 modules                                                                                                         modules by path ./Components/DataLayer/js/store/*.js 9.6 KiB 7 modules                                                                                             modules by path ./Components/_Partials/ 1.91 KiB 3 modules                                                                                                         modules by path ./Components/Mmb/ 6.4 KiB 3 modules                                                                                                                modules by path ./Foundation/Core/*.ts 7.97 KiB 2 modules                                                                                                          + 3 modules                                                                                                                                                      got (ignored) 15 bytes [built] [code generated]                                                                                                                    webpack 5.72.1 compiled successfully in 14000 ms                                                                                                                   COMPLETE: Build Js and Css 2023-06-21 15:57:01Z
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xjbU.png)

Trying to build the project solution successfully(locally).......